# Get quote id on admin new order create page

Tags: magento, quote, discount

I want to add one price match textbox when admin try to create an order.
Like this:

[image]

so when customercare got a customer for price match they just enter amount difference then we give total discount to customer. But I am faceing big problem so when user add amount press enter I am pinging one controller but in that controller I am not able to get quote id I am using:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
echo $session->getId() or $session->getQuoteid();
```

But I am not able to get quote id. And is there any why we can do that. Because we don't want customer item price we want to give full cart discount which help our account team to do there work easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more default way to do this.

1) When you create an order from backend, you enter the customer detailed first.

2) When order page opens, there is a button where says "Add Products", click on it, select the product you want to map with this order.

3) Later, customer will tell the price which means you want to have custom price. In this case there is a checkbox called 'Custom price' under every product item you have added with "Add Products" option (Inside "Items Ordered).

4) When you click on this checkbox, an input will be visible in which you can enter the discounted price. Once you enter the custom price, click on the button below called "Update items and qty's".

5) Item's price will get updated with your custom price. You can proceed with the further order processing now :)

Comment: hi @blastfreak problem is that that custom price discount is on item level ( magento adding discount on item level ) which later create a problem for account. we want to give discount on full order that means if customer said price match ( 20$ difference ) then we want to give $20 discount on whole order so for accountants item price remain same and we give discount on full order.. ( i means cart discount )...